# i wanna get the specific search result not any word like it

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

the $q here is what USERS enter for search , and if he enter a value it returns all products with this value but i wanna get the only equality one,
i think LIKE keyword is my problem .

```
$info = Info::where('code', 'LIKE', '%' . $q . '%')->get();
```

Comment: what do you mean with " only equality one" ... ??? add  a proper data sample and the expected  result

Comment: yea only equality one !

Comment: repeat the words don't help  ..  show a sample  ..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get all the products with the exact term, you can use `=` operator, or even no operator on `where` function. So, you could use these two options:

```
$info = Info::where('code', '=', $q)->get();
```

or

```
$info = Info::where('code', $q)->get();
```

This will return a Collection with several items.

If you want to get just a single product, use `first` instead of `get`:

```
$info = Info::where('code', $q)->first();
```

Answer (score 0):

I think in this situation you can try elastic search DB. It will return a collection with a percentage for maching your search query.

Also for a more professional way check Laravel scout

check this : https://madewithlove.be/how-to-integrate-elasticsearch-in-your-laravel-app-2019-edition/

Answer (score 0):

' like ' use for search if this $q party of string you can make it in first string or last if string or in center

How to use like : https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_like.asp

In your case you shouldn't use like you should use ' = '

$info = Info::where('code', '=' ,$q)->get();
Or 
$info = Info::where('code', $q)->get();
Here by default he use =